# Make setup for two external monitors permanent (nvidia/xorg)

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, xorg

I have a HP Zbook G15 running Ubuntu 22.04 with a Quadro M1000M GPU and two external monitors: One connected to HDMI, one connected with a usb-c to HDMI adapter to the usb-c port. Problem is that I cannot get the setup permanent. I'd like

`Laptop screen (DP-3)  Monitor 1 (DP-0)  Monitor 2 (DP-4)`

Currently I'm getting:

`Monitor 1 (DP-0) Laptop screen (DP-3)  Monitor 2 (DP-4)`

Nice.

I've tried:

- /etc/X11/xorg.conf editing the line of "screens" section

`Option "metamodes" "DP-3: nvidia-auto-select +0+0, DP-0: nvidia-auto-select +1920+0, DP-4: nvidia-auto-select +3840+0"`
which gets fully ignored.

- Running the xrandr command

`xrandr --output DP-3 --pos 0x0 --output DP-0 --pos 1920x0 --output DP-4 --pos 3840x0`

This actually works, but I don't know how to make it permanent. Tried .xsession, .xprofile and .xinit but I don't know if done so correctly. Which should work? And how to do it correctly? Thanks.